# Dynamic conversion of List<Object> to List<T> in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, casting, java-8

I have function like below:

```
public Event convertModelToEvent(List<Object> reportingObject,String Feedname) {
        Event event = new Event();

        event.setHeaderReference(new HeaderReference());
        Class<?> classType = Class.forName(Feedname);

        List<classType> mythings = (List<classType>) (Object) reportingObject;

        event.setPayload(new Payload(reportingObject));
        event.setSpecifications(Lists.newArrayList());

        return event;
    }
```

In method parameter Feedname is nothing but the class name, now I want to convert that

```
List<Object> to List<Feedname>
```

Feedname may be any class name.

Can anyone please suggest what else I can do with it.

Comment: So what happens if I provide a list of say . . . `WindowConstants` and a string `JLabel`?

Comment: How about the simple loop? for(Object obj: reportingObject){
   mythings .add(obj);
}

Comment: am not able set the type parameter with a value "classType". It show error on the line List<classType> mythings = (List<classType>) (Object) reportingObject;

Comment: Java is strongly typed language. You can use dynamics c value as generic type parameter. At best, you can use List<?>. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this happening through casting. You have to iterate through the Object collection transferring references into the T collection. *Maybe* you can use List.addAll(List list); I am not right now set up with my IDE to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

If Feedname can be any class, at best you can construct `List<?>` .
You can do this :

```
List<?> mythings = reportingObject.stream()
    .map(classType::cast)
    .collect (Collectors.toList())
```